# Overriding a radgrid row with a sliding popup when i click on delete option

Tags: asp.net, ajax, radgrid

I have a problem with radGrid Control..

According to my clients requirement we are displaying data in radGrid. But what my problem is, when we click on delete button, the row which has to be delete should be replace with a sliding popup asking " Are u sure you want to delete this row" and with two buttons.

I have tried a lot, but I didn't get any solution for that..

Can any one please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Well, do you have to have a "sliding" popup?  In-built it supports a nice radwindow element for the prompt, which you may be able to programmably slide.  Set these properties on the gridcommandcolumn: `ConfirmTitle="Delete Medical Home" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"`.  Otherwise, you can give the button an OnClientClick value that fires a function to show the prompt, and manually control the postback for the delete.  For the latter this requires some research, I'm not exactly sure how that works with the RadGrid (the postback to submit the command).

HTH.

Brian